# Use special characters other than "\n" and "\0" in C

Tags: c, file, character-encoding, ascii, special-characters

I have one question.
I'm writing some code in C, on UNIX.
I need to write a special character in a file, because I need to divide my file in small sections.

Example:

```
'SPECIAL_CHARACTER'
section 1 with some text
'SPECIAL_CHARACTER'
section 2 with some text
```

etc..

I was thinking to use character '\1'.It seems to work, but it is ok? Or It is wrong?

To do these things without using characters like "\0" or "\n" what should I do?

Comment: Using control-A `'\001'` or `'\1'` is OK.  Any of the control characters except control-G (`'\007'`) through control-M (`'\015'`) — alert, backspace, tab, newline, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return — could be used reasonably sanely.

Comment: You can write any character code in hexadecimal inside a string with `\x01` style

Comment: Ok perfect so I can use '\1' without problems? Moreover, what are all the possible characters I can use in c? More precisely where can I find a list of them?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Ok, but what is the limit?

Comment: Any byte can be written like that, and multibyte with multiple bytes. So there’s no limit.

Comment: Just realize that other applications won't understand what you're doing. You might as well write a binary file instead of mixing text with special characters.

Comment: The choice is largely up to you.  The control characters (bytes) 0x00..0x1F are good choices, and largely independent of code set.  Bytes from 0x7F up to 0xFF are more problematic — their interpretation (at least from 0x80 up) depends heavily on the code set.  What works OK in ISO 8859-1 doesn't work well in UTF-8, for example (whereas the control characters are the same in both).  Also consider whether using `Section 1:\n` to introduce section one would work OK.

Comment: Byte values 0x00 to 0x1F are reserved in ASCII (and therefore standards based on it like ISO-8859, Unicode, etc.), but only a few are commonly used in text (CR, LF, Tab, maybe FF, BS, Esc). Any of the others (including 0x01 "Start of Header") would probably be OK. If you want to stay true to the spirit of ASCII, I suggest 0x1E "Record Separator".

Comment: I see no point in doing that; wouldn't be much better if you wrote your sections in the `length text newline` format, eg. with `printf("%zu %s\n", strlen(str), str)`? That would be much more robust and easier to parse. If space *really* is at a premium, you can omit the extra space and newline and use some variable length integer encoding like [this](https://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/varint.wiki) for the length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hear two different questions where you ask **"Or It is wrong?"**

I hear you asking "how can I designate a separator byte in my code?", and I hear you asking "what is a good choice for a separator byte?"

**First**, fundamentally, what you are asking about is covered in section 6.4.4.4 of the C language specification, which covers "C Character Constants".  There are various places you can look up the formal C language spec, or you can search for "C Character Constants" for perhaps a friendlier description, etc.

In detail, a handful of letters can be used in escape sequences to stand in for single bytes of specific values; e.g., `\n` is one of those, as a stand-in for `0x0a` (decimal 10), a byte designated (in ASCII) as a newline.  Here are the legal ones:

```
\a \b \f \n \r \t \v
```

The escape sequences `\0` and `\1` work because C supports using `\` followed by digits as an octal value.  So, that'll also work with, say, `\3` and `\35`, but not `\9`, and note that `\35` has a decimal value of 29.  (Google "octal values" if you don't immediately see why that's the case.)

There are other legal escape sequences:

```
\' \" \\ \?    :   '  "  \  and  ?, respectively
\xNNNN...      :   each 'N' can be a hexadecimal digit
```

And, of course, escape sequences are just one aspect of C character constants.

**Second**, whether or not you *should* use a given byte value as your file's section separator depends entirely on how your program will be used.  As others have pointed out in the comments, there are commonplace prevailing practices on what sort of byte value to use for this sort of thing.

I personally agree that `0x1e` makes perhaps the most sense since in ASCII it is the "record separator".  Conforming to ASCII can matter if the data will need to be understood by other programs, or if your program will need to be understood by other people.

On the other hand, a simple code comment can make it clear to anyone reading your code what byte value you are using for separating sections of your data file, and any program that needs to understand your data files needs to 'know' a lot more about the file format than just what the record separator is.  There is nothing magical about `0x1e` : it is merely a convention, and a reserved spot on the ASCII table to facilitate a common need -- that is, record separation of text that could contain normal text separators like space, newline, and null.

Broadly, any byte value that won't show up in the contents of your sections would make a fine section separator.  Since you say those contents will be text, there are well over 100 choices, even if you exclude `\0` (`0x00`) and `\n` (`0x0a`).  In ASCII, a handful of byte values have been set aside for this sort of purpose, so that helps reduce the choice from several dozen to just several.  Even among those several, there are only a few commonly used as separators.